# I have create procedure code,what is the delete procedure code

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have create procedure code, what is a delete procedure code.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[saveemp]
   @Empname varchar(50),    
   @EmpAddress varchar(50),    
   @EmpDOB int,    
   @EmpGender varchar(50)
as
begin
    insert employee(Empname, EmpAddress, EmpDOB, EmpGender)    
    values (@Empname, @EmpAddress, @EmpDOB, @EmpGender)
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Delete Procedure' ? Do you want to delete the whole table or a single column?

Comment: not whole table,only particular rows or columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `into` in insert statement

```
insert into employee(Empname,EmpAddress,EmpDOB,EmpGender)
values
(@Empname,@EmpAddress,@EmpDOB,@EmpGender)
```

---

for deleting row using procedure

```
Create procedure [dbo].[deleteempname]
@Empname varchar(50)
as 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM employee WHERE Empname= @Empname
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "drop procedure"? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174969.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To delete the whole table, your query will be,

```
DELETE FROM employee
```

And to delete a single row (depending upon a parameter) it will be like,

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE EmpName= @EmpName
```

It will be better if you delete a row depending upon the primary key (if you have any),

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
```